# Intricate Div/Canvas placement

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Introduction:

I've been learning Javascript/CSS/HTML alone by just reading stuff from the internet and its difficult for me to gain a broader perspective of how to accomplish what I want to learning this way.  I'm trying to make a web browser game.

Ultimate goal:

To create a character equipment screen(whose layout resembles the picture below) and a character bag screen. I wish to be able to click an item in the bag and drag and drop it onto the slot it belongs to on the character equipment screen(doesn't have to be drag and drop but would be nice.)  The bag has 10 different slots, each containing a different item and I only want to move one item at a time.

What I tried:

Create four divs for the bag.  One that contains the other three, one that contains a canvas that draws the text "bag" at the top, and two that contain 5 canvas elements each(for each slot in the bag.)  I did this so that I can implement an "onclick" for each canvas so that I can grab an individual item in the bag.

The character Equipment screen seems too complicated to arrange using divs.  The equipment slots aren't arranged in a nice rows and column manner. I want each equipment slot(the things that look like squares) to be able to be clicked individually.  I've tried floating elements and using margins in different ways and it doesn't work right.  I can draw the entire character equipment screen using one canvas but then how can I tell which section of the canvas is being selected when a user clicks on the screen?

Comments:

Is there some way to determine which section of an element a user clicks on when clicked on?  Is there something better than a div that I can use that I've missed?  It also might help if it were possible to make it so that children in a div cannot force the parent div to exceed the width or height that I specify(sometimes the children increase the parents' size and sometimes it doesn't.) When I add children to a div they seem to always add to the right of the last element, not below the last element, even with float.

The Character screen in the image below is drawn from a single canvas.  I want to arrange multiple small canvas'(one for each equipment slot) in the same way within a div(or some other way.) **edit

[image]

Comment: That's an awesome way of defining your project, but where are you stuck? What have you been doing? This is not a place where we can code for you, but would die to help you solve your issue. Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: The picture of the equipment screen shown is actually just a single canvas drawing the screen.  I want to create the character screen using individual canvas; so i caclick them.

Comment: Can you kindly share us the code then?

Comment: The picture shown of the character screen is actually just done by a single canvas.  I want each equipment slot to be its own canvas so that when the character screen is clicked it can be determined which slot was selected.  Sorry the above post was an error.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to share exactly.  There is a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can achieve the correct positioning of the equipment slots canvas' within the equipment screen using absolute positioning, Hadn't occurred to me before.

Comment: If you are using canvas can't you just check if the mouse click was inside of a box that you have drawn and then run some code from that?